# Vuex State returning values differently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a system where I am authenticating and storing user data in Vuex and then validating which views to show or not. I have a property named **LoggedIn** which is simply a boolean to check if user is logged in or not. let me show you the Vuex parts first

**Actions.js**

```
async login({ commit }, loginData) {
    const email = loginData.user.email;
      try {
        commit(USER_REQUEST_START);
        const response = await apolloClient.mutate({
          mutation: loginAccount,
          variables: { email: email },
        });

        router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });

        commit(SET_USER, response.data);

        Vue.prototype.$snotify.success("Login Successfully", {
          showProgressBar: true,
          timeout: 2000,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        commit(USER_REQUEST_ERROR, error);
        Vue.prototype.$snotify.error(error.message || "Some thing went wrong", {
          showProgressBar: true,
          timeout: 2000,
        });
      }
```

},

**mutations.js**

```
import defaultState from './state'

const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, value) {
    state.data = value
    state.loggedIn = true
    state.loading = false
  },
}

export default mutations
```

**login.vue**

```
async submitForm() {
      try {
        const data = await this.$firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        const idTokenResult = await data.user
          .getIdTokenResult()
          .then((data) => data)

        const authTime = idTokenResult.claims.auth_time * 1000
        const sessionDuration = this.getSessionDuraion(
          authTime,
          SESSION_EXPIRE_DAYS,
        )
        const millisecondsUntilExpiration =
          new Date(sessionDuration).getTime() - authTime
        this.$store.dispatch('setUserSession', sessionDuration)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$firebase.auth().signOut()
        }, millisecondsUntilExpiration)
        this.$store.dispatch('login', data)
      } catch (error) {
        this.$snotify.error(
          (error && error.message) || 'Some thing went wrong',
          {
            showProgressBar: true,
            timeout: 2000,
          },
        )
      }
    },
```

this login method validates user sets User State in Vuex and should redirect to dashboard(this is the problem) there is where the below vuejs router action is called

**router.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = store.state.user.loggedIn
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  console.log(store.state.user);
  console.log(store.state.user.loggedIn);
  if (requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next({name: 'Login'})
  } else {
    if (store.state.user.sessionTimeOut && !store.getters.isSessionValid) {
      sessionMixin.methods.clearSessionStorage()
      next({name: 'Login'})
    } else {
      next(true)
    }
  }
})
```

this is where I am running into a problem, **router.beforeEach** is simply used to logged out if not authenticated and other processes. Now when i login the user set the state there is no error though, but a very wierd issue, the condition **isAuthenticated** doesnot work and when i try to console log it it returns **false** the funny part is when I console.log the actual object i do get the correct value please see the below image for more clarification [image]

extremely Odd behavior dont know whats the reason for doing this, can anyone help me out?

Comment: You're redirecting to the dashboard before setting the user.  As for the console behavior, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011168/vue-js-object-in-array-undefined-in-data-from-store/61012523#61012523) answer and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sdjwcerz/) demo

Comment: I never thought it from that perspective thats an excellent catch @Dan can you please write it as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting to the dashboard before setting the user, which will trigger the `loggedIn` check before it's ready.

```js
router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });
commit(SET_USER, response.data);
```

As for the console behavior, when logging an object or array to the console, when you click to expand/view the properties, the console shows you the properties as they are at the time of the *click*, not the time of the *log*.  This is possible because JavaScript objects and arrays are references, so the console is able to update the display by reference.

Here's an illustrative [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sdjwcerz/) of that in action.

<sub>(Converted from my comment as requested.)</sub>