# Vuex getter is undefined but state appears in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-reactivity

I have a slightly strange problem ..
I am not able to return a specific property in my object that is in the "state" of vuex.

To have a better understanding, I'll put a snippet of my store below:

```
state: {
        activeIdentifier: '', //controlar qual modulo que esta ativo
        configListActive: { entity: {} }, //controla qual instancias que esta ativa na visao
        listController: {}, //instancias dos controllers
        filterParams:{}, //params de filtros feitos
    },

    getters: {
        configListActive: state => param =>{            
            console.log("State:", state.configListActive)
            console.log("Param:", param)
            console.log("Result:", state.configListActive[param])
            return state.configListActive[param];
        },
        filterParams: state => param => {
            return state.filterParams[param];
        },
        listController: state => param => {
            return state.listController[param];
        }
    },
[....]
```

I'm passing a parameter in the getters "configListActive", and my object "configListActive" exists the property, however, the return is "undefined", I will put below the print of the debug that I made.

[image]

What could have been done wrong?

Comment: `state.configListActive.entity` doesn't exist when you log `state.configListActive`. But by the time you click to expand, it exists, so the console shows you it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011168/vue-js-object-in-array-undefined-in-data-from-store/61012523#61012523) and [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sdjwcerz/).

Comment: Thansk for answers, but even setting an initial value for the state it returns me as undefined, I changed the initial post by placing the initial state of "configLIstActive", but the return is always the same.

Comment: No problem.  That is not reproducible from the code above (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/4vd8zkbr/))

Comment: My mistake, it was cache in the browser. But my question is now, how can I dynamically leave the values of the "state", since my idea was to define the states dynamically.

Comment: Wherever you set `entity` or any uninitialized object properties, you need to use `Vue.set`.  I posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into one of Vue's [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).  From the docs:

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive... However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, propertyName, value)` method

From within a component you can use:

```js
this.$set(object, propertyName, value)
```

If the caveat was encountered in Vuex, you can import Vue into the Vuex module:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
```

and use `Vue.set` in a mutation like:

```js
Vue.set(state.object, property, value);
```