# Vuex Store Object Child returns undefined, parent returns properly. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I've seen some similar questions but they don't seem to match my situation.

When I log `this.$store.state.account` I get the expected result

```
    {__ob__: Nt}
       user: Object
          favorites_playlist: (...)
          firebaseID: (...)
          spotifyID: (...)
```

However, when I `console.log(this.$store.state.account.user)` the user object disappears! All of the nested properties inside `user` return undefined though they log perfectly fine above

`console.log(this.$store.state.account.user)`

```
{__ob__: Nt}
   __ob__: Nt {value: {…}, dep: vt, vmCount: 0}
   __proto__: Object
```

This is the method inside my component calling the object

```
        async connectToSpotify() {
            console.log("User Profile: ", this.user)
            var firebaseID = await this.$store.dispatch("signInToFirebase")
  
            var authID = await this.$store.dispatch('connectToSpotify')
            Vue.set(this.$store.state.spotify, "authId", authID)

            var userProfile = await this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserDataFromSpotify", authID)
            userProfile["firebaseID"] = firebaseID

    
            this.$store.dispatch("bindCurrentUser", userProfile.spotifyID)

            console.log("this.$store.state")
            console.log(this.$store.state);
            console.log("this.$store.state.account")
            console.log(this.$store.state.account);
            console.log("this.$store.state.account.user")
            console.log(this.$store.state.account.user);
            console.log("this.$store.state.account.user.favorites_playlist")
            console.log(this.$store.state.account.user.favorites_playlist);
            // console.log(this.$store.state.account.user.firebaseID);
             var favorites_playlist = this.$store.state.account.user.favorites_playlist


            var playlistID = await this.$store.dispatch("createFavoritesPlaylist", [authID, userProfile.spotifyID, favorites_playlist])
            console.log(`PlaylistID: ${playlistID}`);

            userProfile["favorites_playlist"] = playlistID
            console.log(this.$store);
            return db.ref(`users/${userProfile.spotifyID}`).update(userProfile)
            
        },
```

this is the action inside my accounts module that binds the user to firebase

```
const state = () => ({
    //user: { voted_tracks: {}, favorited_tracks: {}, favorites_playlist: null, authID: null}
    user: {},
})
const actions = {
    bindCurrentUser: firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef }, id) => {
      return bindFirebaseRef('user', db.ref('users').child(id))
    }),
}
```

Not sure what further information would be relevant aside that `this.$store.state.account.user` is binded via Vuexfire to a database reference. The store is injected into the root component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011168/vue-js-object-in-array-undefined-in-data-from-store/61012523#61012523

Comment: This is awesome! seems like my data wasn't loaded by the time I needed it, will see how I can refactor my code to account for this and check back in

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question but you don't mean literally add `return` before `firebaseAction` do you? it returns an error, how should this line be edited? `return bindFirebaseRef('user', db.ref('users').child(id))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data comes in after the `console.log`.  The console updates object/array logs with current values when you click, but can't do that with primitives.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011168/vue-js-object-in-array-undefined-in-data-from-store/61012523#61012523) for more detail.

It should be enough to `await` the `firebaseAction`:

```js
await this.$store.dispatch("bindCurrentUser", userProfile.spotifyID)
```

```js
bindCurrentUser: firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef }, id) => {
   console.log("account.bindCurrentUser() called");
   return bindFirebaseRef('user', db.ref(`users/${id}`)).then(() => {
       console.log("account.bindCurrentUser() -- complete")
   }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
}),
```

Comment: Hopefully firebase isn't doing too much magic with `firebaseAction`. I don't actually use firebase so I don't know what it's doing to be sure that this works

Comment: Updated my code to include your recommendations here. It doesn't seem like the the `await` code is working. I added `return bindFirebaseRef('user', db.ref('user').child(id)).then(() => console.log("account.bindCurrentUser() -- complete"))` and the log statement is never printed

Comment: I also made sure to declare `async bindCurrentUser()` to make sure that wasn't the issue

Comment: Figured it out!

Comment: Were you able to `await` it properly when using `firebaseAction` directly like that?

Comment: The function needed to be declared as `bindCurrentUser: firebaseAction(({ bindFirebaseRef }, id) => {` and you return `bindFirebaseRef`. I tried editing your answer to show how the function should look, but yes when written correctly I was able to await!

Comment: Ok that means `firebaseAction` returns a function and not a promise (which makes sense in hindsight), that would explain my misconception.  You're welcome, glad you got it figured out